# Scheduling python script in crontab to run on a weekly basis

Tags: python-3.x, shell, cron

We have a master shell script which is scheduled in crontab to run on daily basis. Inside master script, we have multiple shell scripts included, based on the conditions, they will be running in a  subshell.
Here is the example of how master script looks like:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
(

if [[ $(hostname -s) == "host1" ]] ; then

    /tmp/script1.sh
fi

)&


(

if [[ $(date +%a) == "Sun" ]] ; then
   
   /tmp/sundayscript.sh

fi

)&

(

if [[ $(whoami) == "test" ]] ; then
   
   /tmp/test.py > /tmp/test.log

fi

)&
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Unfortunately, python script is not running. logfile is empty all the time, no errors reported.
Script is running fine from shell prompt. Any method to schedule/call a python script inside shell script.
Do we need to set any additional parameters before calling the script.

no results after scheduling in the crontab, result of the file is not generating. Logfile is getting generated as empty file

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -e`

This command will open your user's crontab file for editing. To schedule a Python script to run weekly, you can add a line to the crontab file using the following format:

`0 0 * * 0 /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/your_script.py`

0 0 * * 0: These numbers and asterisks represent the timing of your script. In this example, the script will run at midnight (00:00) every Sunday (0). You can adjust these values to suit your preferred schedule. The five fields represent, in order, minutes (0-59), hours (0-23), days of the month (1-31), months (1-12), and days of the week (0-7, where both 0 and 7 represent Sunday).